# Provide Internet access to two machines without WiFi

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 7 and a desktop with Windows XP.

I want to provide internet access from the same ISP to both laptop as well as the desktop using LAN cables without using WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Get a router and have it connect directly to the modem and put the PC and laptop on the LAN side of the router.
2. Add another Ethernet port to the PC and use [internet connection sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing). Connect the PC to the laptop – use a crossover cable for that connection.